# Identifing Google Drive Change types

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have been developing web application checking if there were any changes in Google Drive files. It takes care about several folders and use Google Drive API changes.

So far I am trying to get all files from watched folders, save their state (name, parent folder, etc.), get list of changes from GDrive API, then looking  for changes with matching FileId and finally compare state before and after change.

I would like to know that is there any easier way to determine a kind of change (moving/deleting files, changing names)?

Answer (score 1):

A change is either a deletion (`deleted` will be set to `true`) or it is one of the others. The file ID will always be consistent, so you can determine yourself the type of change:

- Has the name changed?
- Have the parents changed?